# Symfony FOSUserBundle Role array

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I use This function to get data

```
public function UserAction()
{
    $easyuser = $this->getDoctrine()->getrepository('AppBundle:User')->findall();
    foreach($easyuser as $user){
            $id = $user->getid();
            $username =  $user->getUsername();
            $email =  $user->getEmail();
            $roles =  $user->getRoles();
    }

    return $this->render('easycall/user.html.twig', ['easyuser' => $easyuser, 'roles' => $roles]);
}
```

and in twig i use this code to show data

```
                {% for entity in easyuser %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{entity.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{entity.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{entity.email}}</td>
                        {% for role in entity.roles %}
                            <td>{{role}}</td>
                        {% endfor %} 
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that i get all the roles if the user is ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, i want to get only the first value from every array.

i tried something like reset() but it did'nt work, any suggestion??

This is also a picture how the results look likes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st  item  from  array  shoul be somethink like

```
{{entity.roles | first}}
```

but it's simply 1st  item from  array,  i'm  not  sure if it  always  be  more "powerfull role"